# Is it possible to change designer attribute in a LWC (not aura) that is on a flexipage without first removing the LWC from the Flexipage?

Tags: lightning-web-components, flexipages, design-attributes

Today what we do is delete the LWC from Flexipage with a predeployment manual step and then it gets deployed through the package with update designer attributes.

Is there a way to skip that?

Comment: In theory, if the name in the flexipage and LWC are in the same deployment, it should work. If not, I don't think there's a way to fix this (but you could automate the first deployment, too).

Comment: curious on the automation?

Comment: You can deploy the flexipage without the designer attribute set in one deployment, then a second deployment with the flexipage using the new attribute with the LWC code that exposes it.